# Template management similar to Shopify - Architecture Recommendations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, architecture

We made a SAAS platform for community management. We have been requested to give customized experience for each community and eventually end community managers would like to modify the views / element locations / css / js . With a lot of research , we have decided to go with Shopify#liquidmarkup http://liquidmarkup.org/. What would be the ideal way to store these templates and where ?

Here is our current models architecture

Communities has_many Users

And hence communities would have their own rails "layouts" / "partials" / "liquidtemplates" . We are planning to store their layouts in the file system currently this way

Rails.root > templates > community_uuid > community_specific_template_files

But as our communities scale up, we would have to too many "templates" folders piled up. Even though they are ignored in MAINAPP git repo, on the app server with multiple unicorn nodes, these templates must be available for any unicorn server at any given point of time. This would exponentially increase the Filesystem Space consumed as our community base increases on our App servers.

We have 3 options currently

1. Store them on File system and deploy / update templates on all application servers  - IO operation
2. Store templates in database and cache those template queries
3. Store templates in REDIS as a HASH structure and retrieve accordingly .

Would love to know your thoughts ?

Thanks
Vivek Sampara

Answer (score 0):

1. Feels really unstable. Must deal with:

   - Nodes being away when sync-procedure starts.
   - Nodes going down during update procedure, it will be "semi-synced" and must be re-synced when back up.
   - Must have separate process that triggers sync procedure when new nodes gets added.

Do you plan to implement this on you own or does unicorn/ruby have some built-in functionality taking care of this?

2. Feels like a more sensible solution. But you always want to keep the database queries to a minimum.
3. This is the solution I personally would prefer. Having a dedicated Redis-instance acting like a template repository.

Comment: Thanks for you inputs @Vic . Can you explain "Nodes being away" and "semi-synced" ?

Comment: My concerns about the first option was in general terms. Concerns about having a synced file system in a multiserver environment. Its hard to garantie that all servers/instances/nodes are available during the sync procedures. And how to handle the case when a server/instance/node goes down and reboots (for an unrelated issue) during the sync procedure